# Why is nginx on Ubuntu 22.04 giving me a 404 Not Found when root is under a directory other than /var/www?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, http-status-code-404, ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-22.04

I installed nginx on fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install and I wanted to move `root` to `/home/ubuntu/sites/html` instead of the original `/var/www/html` but it kept giving me a 404 Not Found error. However, when I installed nginx with the exact same config on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install everything worked fine. Does anybody know whether Ubuntu 22.04 puts some restriction on the location of nginx root so that it can only be served from a directory under `/var/www`? Is there any config I can change so that files can be served from say, `/home/ubuntu/sites/html`? Any help would be appreciated.

My server block file looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /home/ubuntu/sites/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

I've compared all config files related to nginx on both Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04 servers and they are all exactly the same except for two files in `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled`:

`50-mod-http-geoip2.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-geoip2.conf`

and

`70-mod-stream-geoip2.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-stream-geoip2.conf`

which are on Ubuntu 22.04 but not on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Turns out everything also works fine if you put your files in a directory/mount under /mnt.